# How can I have the same time as my system?

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

```html
create_date = fields.Datetime(default=fields.Datetime.now, string='Creation Date', readonly=True, index=True)
```

If I display it on a form it gives me the system exact hour for example if it is now 11/08/2017 15:12:00 on the form I saw the same but the problem is when I do something with it, it considers it like 11/08/2017 14:12:00

for example:

```html
    @api.onchange('name')
    def onchange_name(self):
        if self.name:
            raise exceptions.except_orm(_('test'), _(self.create_date))
```

it displays 2017-08-11 14:12:00

***NB:***
On the country we are UTC+1

Comment: the time on my machine is UTC+1

Comment: odoo on forms displays UTC+1 but if I wanna do a treatment with it, it considers it as just UTC

Answer (score 0):

Odoo always stores Datetime in UTC and convert it to the Timezone of the user on the the view (to support multi timezone). You must convert the Datetime to your timezone. You can may be try it: (not tested :))

```py
from odoo.tools import DEFAULT_SERVER_DATETIME_FORMAT
import pytz

@api.onchange('name')
def onchange_name(self):
    if self.name:
        if  self.env.user.tz:
            user_tz = pytz.timezone(self.env.user.tz)
            utc_create_date = datetime.strptime(self.create_date, DEFAULT_SERVER_DATETIME_FORMAT)
            create_date = pytz.utc.localize(utc_create_date, is_dst=None).astimezone(user_tz)
            raise exceptions.except_orm(_('test'), create_date.strftime(DEFAULT_SERVER_DATETIME_FORMAT)) 
        raise exceptions.except_orm(_('test'), self.create_date)
```

Comment: Even if I try raise exceptions.except_orm(_('test'), "second if")  after if  self.env.user.tz: . it doesn't display anything, it is like it doesn't enter to that condition

Comment: Did you set the timezone in Odoo?

Comment: dun think so, is it possible?

Comment: You can set the timezone in the user form for each user.